# Missing ";" before statement

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntax-error, node-red

I can't figure out where I made a mistake in the syntax, please help. The error is in the first line. I made everything else before I did the first line and the error wasn't there before I made it.

```
    String msg.payload2 = msg.payload.toLowerCase();
if (msg.payload2 == "-coinflip") {
    rnd = Math.floor (Math.random() * (2-0));
    if (rnd == 1) {
        msg.payload = "Heads";
    } else {
        msg.payload = "Tails";
    }
}
return msg.payload
```

Comment: `String` before `msg.payload2` is wrong, perhaps you want `let` or `const`? javascript is no statically typed language thus there are no type identifiers in variable declarations. Also you are missing a `;` after `return msg.payload`.

Comment: @Xatenev you can't have a variable with a `.` in :) well written like that anyway

Comment: Just remove the `String` an all will be good

Comment: Possibly, you can use some online syntax validator for this kind of question. One such example is : http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html

Answer (score 4):

`msg` is already an object therefore you can add properties without further declaration. And there is no need to cast a variable to anything in JS.

Your code should be:

```
msg.payload2 = msg.payload.toLowerCase();
if (msg.payload2 == "-coinflip") {
    rnd = Math.floor (Math.random() * (2-0));
    if (rnd == 1) {
        msg.payload = "Heads";
    } else {
        msg.payload = "Tails";
    }
}
return msg.payload
```

Comment: thanks, both this code and the other answer work, though my problem is that msg.payload ends up as "-coinflip" while i need it to be "heads" or "tails". would you know how to fix the problem?

Comment: maybe you could use something like `return (rnd === 1) ? 'Heads' : 'Tails';` instead the msg object.

Comment: im pretty sure i have no choice but to use the msg object, this is for a discord bot and if i dont change msg.payload it'll just repeat what i sent in chat. I also made a mistake in my original code, im supposed to return msg and not msg.payload, i hope that didnt cause a misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is loosely typed. When accessing a property on an object, using the syntax `msg.payload2` you should receive the value contained in the property `payload2` from the `msg` object. However, if the property doesn't exist, the `payload2` property will return undefined. This is why your code worked before adding the first line in your example.

This line:

`if (msg.payload2 == "-coinflip")`

will always evaluate to `false` if the `payload2` property is never defined.

The reason it didn't work when you added line 1 of your code snippet in; is that you're trying to give a type to an object property in JavaScript using syntax that the JS engine doesn't understand and will throw a `SyntaxError`.

EDIT:

```js
let msg = { payload: '' }; // assuming this is an object defined higher up. I've placed this here for more context
let result;
msg.payload2 = msg.payload && msg.payload.toLowerCase(); // This line also protects against trying to lowercase an undefined payload
if (msg.payload2 == "-coinflip") {
    rnd = Math.floor (Math.random() * (2-0));
    if (rnd == 1) {
        result = "Heads";
    } else {
        result = "Tails";
    }
}
return result;
```

I don't consider this production code but it will get your app running.

Comment: i was trying to define msg.payload2 with the first line, but since it clearly doesn't work, how do you recommend i do it? changing msg.payload2 to hello or something doesn't fix it

Comment: Posted a snippet above. Let me know if you still have troubles.

Comment: thanks, both this code (with a bit of editing for nodered) and the other answer work, though my problem is that msg.payload (i edited it so that msg.payload = result and then it returns msg, since it always needs to return msg in nodered) ends up as "-coinflip" while i need it to be "heads" or "tails". would you know how to fix the problem?